# How do I test if a certain g:link is the current URL being rendered?

Tags: url, grails, menu

I'm using the `g:link` tag to create a simple menu for my webapp:

```
<ul>
    <li class="active">
        <g:link controller="dashboard">Dashboard</g:link>
    </li>
    <li>
        <g:link controller="projects">Projects</g:link>
    </li>
    ...
</ul>
```

But I need to output `class="active"` whenever the link corresponds to the current URL.

What is the best or most commonly used way to do this in Grails?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the above case I would simply write it like this:

```
<ul>
    <li class="${controllerName == 'dashboard' ? 'active' : ''}">
        <g:link controller="dashboard">Dashboard</g:link>
    </li>
    <li class="${controllerName == 'projects' ? 'active' : ''}">
        <g:link controller="projects">Projects</g:link>
    </li>
    ...
</ul>
```

In the general case, it can be tricky. You would either have to compare at least `controllerName`, `actionName` and `params` to the link parameters or get the current URL as string and compare it to the output `g.createLink(..)` - but of course a different order of params would break that logic.

Comment: So there is no generic tool to build menus in grails? Maybe I should write my own tag then.

Comment: Tags are very nice and simple to write so writing your own tag is a very good idea. That said there are some plugins that may help you build navigation menus, perhaps most notably the [Plugin Platform Core plugin](http://grails.org/plugin/platform-core) though personally I find it a bit cumbersome as soon as you try to tweak it too much. I'd definitely start with a template or taglib.